# Il s'agit de + à quoi je ressemble

Tags: grammaire, traduction, prépositions

I would to say in French "it's all about the way I look". I know how to say "it's about" (*Il s'agit de*) and "the way I look" (*à quoi je ressemble*), but I don't know how to combine these two phrases, because *d'à quoi* seems very wrong.

Comment: I must ask a precision from you; do you make a difference between "It's **all** about the way I look." and "It's  about the way I look."?; it seems to me there should be one, but again it could be otherwise.

Comment: Not really, "it's about the way I look" also conveys what I had in mind. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

« Il s'agit d'à quoi je ressemble. » sounds very odd, as you say.

The following is acceptable, but there are other ways to express it as well:

> Il s'agit  de ce à quoi je ressemble.

Other similar options:

> Il  s'agit  de mon apparence personnelle.
>   C'est une question de mon apparence personnelle.
>   Çela a à voir avec ce à quoi je ressemble.

The following translations are found in the dictionary "reverso".

> Now it's all about believing. → Maintenant, tout est dans la foi.
>  
>   See, it's all about sizing up your opponent. → Tout est dans l'évaluation de ton ennemi.
>  
>   She says it's all about the case, but it's not. →  Elle dit qu'il s'agit de l'affaire mais ce n'est pas le cas.
>   For me, it's all about justice. →  Pour moi, il s'agit de justice.
>   Apparently it's all about the landing. → Apparemment, tout est dans l'atterrissage.
>   Look, it's all about appearance. → Regardez, tout n'est qu'apparence.

Comment: @Montéedelait  Bar that I meant "right" as far as syntax goes, which can be neglected anyway, it's better or equivalent as I see it; so that's fine.

Comment: @Montéedelait A second translation is given in the same list, but it seems it's only subject to the context whether to use one or the other: "Look, it's all about appearance." →" Tout est une question d'apparence.".  1/ tout est fait pour afficher une apparence (tout n'est qu'apparence). 2/ in the concern at hand everything is a matter of appearance (tout est une question d'apparence).

Answer (score 4):

On a grammatical note, let's first point out that there is a way to combine “s'agir de” and “à quoi”. Here is an example:

> S'agit-il de **ce** à quoi je pense ? (*Is it what I think it is?*)

However, in your case “s'agir de” wouldn't match the “*it's **all** about*”. You need a different phrase to express this. Here is one way to translate “it's all about the way I look”, which should work in most contexts¹:

> Ce qui importe c'est mon look².

or using variants :

> Ce qui est important / c'est ce à quoi je ressemble.
>   La seule chose qui importe / c'est mon apparence.

But there are probably many more ways to phrase this in a given context.

—
<sup>1. The way you look could be at stake, or something else that will depend on how you look.</sup>
<sup>2. Commonly used as a noun in French</sup>

Comment: "Ce qui importe c'est mon look;" means "What matters is the way I look."; there is an error somewhere.

Comment: @LPH Il s'agit bien de la traduction de la phrase anglaise. Je porte des verres fumés la nuit. "It's all about looking cool" → Ce n'est pas à cause de la lumière, ça a tout à voir avec le look que je désire avoir.

Comment: "What' it all about" means "De quoi s'agit-il?"; that's taken out of a dictionary; in reverso you find as a translation of "it's all about" the phrase "tout cela concerne"; it is not the same as "ce qui est important", in no way at all.

Comment: “What is this all about?” → «De quoi s’agit-il?» ou «Pourquoi toute cette agitation?». “It's all about the way I look” → grosso modo «Mes décisions peuvent vous sembler bizarres, mais elle se justifient entièrement par le fait que je suis prêt à sacrifier un peu de bon sens au profit de mon apparence».